# Is This Educational Model of Relativity Right?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity

After watching and reading about Special Relativity I am still left with some questions unanswered. Can you please tell me if this educational model of relativity, simplified to level of a cartoon, broadly right:

- There is a rail cab with passenger moving on tracks at a constant speed and stationary observer on the railway station.
- As he approaches speed of light, the rail cab passenger's time runs slower and slower and lengths around him, in a direction of travel, become shorter and shorter.

My questions are related to how these events will look from both passenger's and stationary observer's perspective?

- Is it right to say that the stationary observer is going to see the rail cab  passenger's body movements like in a slow motion movie?

  Is the reverse of the above right? Is the passenger going to see stationary observer's body movements moving like in a 'fast forward' move, unnaturally sped up?
- Is passenger going to appear to stationary observer as shrinking in length along the direction of travel and slowly turning into a pancake?

  And the reverse, is the passenger going to see the stationary observer becoming fatter and fatter, i.e. stretching out in the direction of passenger's movement?

Comment: One thing to consider is that there's no "reverse" case. The man on the ground sees the train passenger moving at high speed, contracting in length, and with a slow clock. But, the train passenger considers himself stationary, so he considers the man on the ground moving at high speed, contracting in length, and with a slow clock. It's really important to consider where your observer is - how you see the world is relative to your frame of reference!

Comment: OK, they both have their own separate perspectives. But I need to clarify. Is the passenger going to see stationary observer moving like in 'fast-forward' motion. And is stationary observer going to see passenger moving as in 'slow-motion' movie.

Comment: No. The stationary observer sees the passenger move slowly with respect to themselves, and the passenger sees the 'stationary' observer move slowly with respect to themselves. Every object observes that clocks run slower on other objects that move with respect to it. There is no frame from which other moving objects have a *faster* clock.

Comment: ok, I am no expert, but that doesn't add up. They can't both look as if slowing down, because than there is no symmetry. If passenger's time is running slower, than 1 second in passenger's time is (for example) 2 seconds in stationary observer's time. When they fly atomic clocks around the world, after the end of the journey, one of the clocks will show directly on its dial that more time had passed. In other words one clock was running faster and the other clock was running slower. They can't both be slower?

Comment: Actually, both thinking the other clock more slowly is exactly the symmetry you want.

Comment: If you want to understand relativity, you should read a book.  My favorite is Mermin's Space and Time in Special Relativity.

Comment: Yeah, books are not really the best method. After reading a book, I usually have more questions than before reading it. There are always subtle assumptions which author considers self-evident, while for the reader they are a blind spot. Like for example, here, I was stuck on 'symmetry' and 'reciprocity' until Clever and rmhleo pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @COROVICD: After reading a book you should have DIFFERENT questions than before. The "subtle assumptions" that you can't locate are spelled out quite explicitly in textbooks on physics, starting with a good high school text.

Answer (score 2):

You are fixing on the concept of 'stationary' S and 'moving' M observer as absolute, and the theory of relativity on the contrary, abandons these absolute definitions.

There is no absolutely 'stationary' nor absolutely 'moving' observer, because this would contradict other phenomena observed, like the constancy of the speed of light.

And what you are expressing is more like a theory of reciprocals, where if one observer see time/space change, the other sees the opposite in such a way that both cancel.

If you want to see it simple, here is guidelines:

> Everything I see moving, has slower time and shorter length than me (in the direction of movement).

The trick is that the above statement is true for any observer. Any observer can make the same claims over what they see moving. That is why the observer in the station sees the moving conductor in these conditions, but the conductor sees the moving observer in the station also under the same conditions: slower time and shorter length.

This seems counter intuitive, but is how reality is. Is only that the reality of everyday allow us to accept that whatever stands still with earth, is absolutely stationary. But this is just a convention for earthlings, convenient but just conventional. The martians could make the same claim over Mars, and then for them nothing on Earth would be stationary ever. Who would be right?

Well until Einstein we thought that the correct stationary place should be the cosmos, the space where all stars and galaxies and planets exist. We thought this because we believed that this space was like a an empty room: their corners are always there whatever happens inside. So an observer absolutely is still if he sees the corners of the room immovable, and otherwise that observer will be absolutely moving.

This is not true in reality. We are like in a room in darkness where the corners are invisible, so we have to measure our movement with respect to another moving body inside the room. Admittedly, that body could be moving or not, but since we don't see the corners, we could not know.

At this point we discover something else, there is something absolutely moving with the same velocity for us and for any other body moving w.r.t. us: light. So light speed is absolute for all, this tears apart the idea of a room which corners are the judges of what moves and what doesn't.

With this new hint, I cannot construct the room very well on my mind, to convey it to you. But you can look at it this way: before, you could accept that if something moves from my perspective then that something will see me moving from their perspective. Well the 'room' we live in is such an odd one, that what I see moving will not only look like moving, but it will have different properties than if it was resting w.r.t. me, i.e. will have a slower time (or look in slow motion) and will be shorter in the moving direction.

Other way you can look at it: before you could accept that it is possible to say that something is absolutely resting. This is like saying it was absolutely with $v_r=0$. Well reality has shown we live in a world where the 'absolute' velocity, maybe some type of new 'resting velocity' (in a different concept of resting) is in fact the speed of light $v_r=c$.

Comment: I only joined today, so I can "up" your answer, but this is the best answer ever. Not everybody has ability to explain things or understand what is confusing other people. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad it answers your question. I don't agree with the downvotes, they seem to imply that is not a valid question, which I don't share. They also might discourage users from asking questions without having a certain level of understanding, and then what would the purpose of this site be?